# MySQL Workbench alter table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, alter-table

I create a table with mysql workbench.

The screenshot before "Apply";

[image]

It creates the table without any error.

After "Alter Table..." the screenshot;

[image]

Is this a turkish character problem?
How can i fix it?

Comment: Column datatypes are not the same...

Comment: Looking at the SQL it generates can help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot I would gues that the datatypes: (10) (11) and the empty one are the problem.

If not you should post the error message (it should contain the generated sql).